# SQL Azure Data Sysnc Issue

Tags: sql, synchronization, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

The use case is Distributed deployment of Web Application on Azure using PaaS. I read the Azure documentation on SQL Azure database geo-replication, and it seems none of the services tiers best fit this need. The other option is SQL Sync, which is in preview and cannot be used in production.It seems Microsoft Azure does not have any way for a redundant database centric application using PaaS model.
Please help how to resolve the issue or any alternate solution.

Akanksha

Answer (score 0):

Both SQL Data Sync and Geo-replication are for database redundant using. But we need to know you detailed scenarios, so that we can say which one is more fit. Basically Geo-replication is DB level data synchronization used for DR. SQL Data Sync is Table level data synchronization used for reference data replication for both Azure DB and On-prem DB.

Comment: please add more content to answer on use cases of both